# Google form anonymity in organization

Tags: google-forms, google-workspace-for-business

I have a Google account that's part of an organisation. There's this form that only people in the same organisation can respond to. Is there a way for the owner of the organisation to find out that it was me who submitted a response to the Google form?

Comment: not possible, unless you submit the form at 23:50 as the last employee at work and sign off from work at 23:55 - then anyone can tell it was you

Comment: and unless the person behind the form is psycho and created individual form per each employee sent via email and claimed to be the "collective form"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a form in an organisation, the creator has the option to select "Collect email address" which will automatically collect usernames. According to the [help article for this option](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en) (see "Collect respondents’ email addresses"), if it is enabled:

> ... they will be required to enter their email address before they submit the form.
>
> If you use a Google account through work or school, respondents will see a message at the top explaining that their username will be collected automatically.

So if there is no email field and there is no message saying your username will be collected automatically, the survey will be anonymous. If it isn't, your responses will be identifiable.

Comment: but how to check if it is annonimous when you are not creator of the form? In other words how to check if your email wil be collected?